# Jenkins - Slave user change

Tags: macos, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a MAC slave connected to my Jenkins master via Java WebStart (SSH not working).
I have an administrator user called 'qalab' who has logged into the m/c (it never sleeps).
Node system information is shown as the given image.

[image]

Now, I need to launch Safari browser via Selenium. 
Whenever i run the test with Safari i get the below exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The expected Safari data directory does not exist: /Users/null/Library/Safari

(Chrome and Firefox works fine)

Selenium looks for Safari in /Users/ user.name /Library/Safari

I tried like this.

System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", "/Users/qalab/Library/Safari");

But still, it does not seem to take this path and fails with above exception.

Is there any way to fix this?
Also why does it show the user.name as root.  How to change it to my user - 'qalab'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to run your slave as Root (which the above information indicates you are doing).  Jenkins slaves have no inherent need to have escalated privileges (we run our Master and Slave with non-administrator accounts) as long as your Jenkins home directory is in someplace they can access.  In your case, your Jenkins home directory above appears to be `/`, which is probably not what you want to do, since you will run into permission problems if you aren't root.

Any directory under your `qalab` user's home should work, as should any other directory that you create as long as the `qalab` user has privileges to read/write/execute on it (we tend to use a `/Development/Jenkins` directory, but that's an historical preference for us).

From one of our slaves:

```
user.dir    /Development/Jenkins
user.home   /Users/buildbot
user.name   buildbot
```

Our master is similarly configured, and both work fine for us.

Comment: Sir, I understand. however, i do not know where to change the user.home!!  My node is configured as Remote FS Root=/Users/qalab/jenkins

Comment: The problem is that you're running Jenkins as Root.  If you run it as `qalab`, you will be much happier.  You don't want to change the user.home for root, that could be catastrophic.   The comments about the Jenkins home directory was about user.dir, which is also ill-advisedly located.   That is changeable by setting JENKINS_HOME in your environment before launching the slave.  Make sure to launch it as your `qalab` user, though.